# How to display the content on the form on same page in grid view?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, rendering

I am creating a `replication form` .The content of the form need to be displayed below the form.

**my code:-**
 IN `employee.rb`

```
class EmployeeController < ApplicationController
def emain
    @replication  =  Replication.new
    @repications = Replication.find(:all)
end
def create
    @replication = Replication.new(params[:replication])
        if @replication.save
            flash[:success] = "Replication Added Successfully"
            redirect_to employee_emain_path
        end
    else
        redirect_to pages_home_path
end
end
```

**in (`views/employee/emain`):-**

```
<div class = "container">
<hr>
<div class = "span9">
    <div class = "well">
        <%= render "/employee/form" %>
    </div>
<hr>
       Display all replication slip <br/>
     <% if !@replications.blank? %>
        <%= for item in (@replications) %>
          <%= item.sr_no %>
        <% end %>
      <% else %>
     <% end %>
</div>
```

**PROBLEM:-**
 It does not show any error but does not display the contents.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you not able to see the part below "Display all replication slip" ?

Comment: Please post your form content and filename.